# VBA returning integer instead of date format

Tags: excel, vba

So Ive tried multiple different ways to check and see if a value in a celll has a date in it, and if so, return the date in a date format instead of the integer excel normally associates with it. However, Ive tried many different apporaches and still get the number as the output and not a date format

Here is my latest rendition, would anyone like to point out where Im wrong?

```
Set rRng = sheet.Range("a1:a2500")
For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
If IsDate(rCell) Then
    rCell = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = rCell
Else
    wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = rCell
End If
```

Comment: I am just guessing what you want to achieve. But I'd suggest changing `rCell = Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")` to `rCell.Numberformat = "mm/dd/yyyy"`. Remember: a date remains a date and thereby a number (as you correctly pointed out). Yet, the `.NumberFormat` allows us to change how the number is shown on an Excel sheet (purely visual representation).

Comment: Didnt work, but when i tried "wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 6).Value = rCell.Offset(0, 6).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"" this in a couple of spots, it didnt work on short dates (either), but on dates with converted integer that contained a decimal(prolly b/c of time/date stamp), it returned "false:"

Answer (score 0):

This worked perfectly!

```
 wsO.Cells(wsO.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(0, 5).Value = CDate(rCell.Offset(0, 5))
```

CDate did the trick :)